# Is there a way to use ByteBuddy to proxy both method calls & property access?

Tags: java, dynamic, byte-buddy

I'm looking into creating a fixture system similar to that of PyTest's for Java. As such I'm looking to have methods such as:

```java
public Fixture<Connection> connection(){
  return Fixtures.provide(()->{
  //set up connection
  return connection;
  }).teardown(()->{//teardown logic});
}
public Fixture<Database> database(Connection connection){
  return Fixtures.provide(()->new Database(connection.getURL()));
}
```

My current design has a "Fixture scanning phase" before any tests. This loads all fixtures into memory, so reflection access of these methods only has to be called once. After being loaded, fixtures are managed with `enable` and `disable` when relevant.

As you may notice, **functionally** I don't need the connection object when *creating* the Database fixture by calling the method via reflection, since it is only used within the *setup* logic of the fixture (the lambda), not the *creation* logic (the method call). However, **practically** I do need the object during creation to give to the setup logic lambda.

The problem is that we run into a circle - we need the setup `Connection` to create the `Database`, but the `Connection` is not set up yet when looking for fixtures *before* testing. I have a few options to solve this, which I may adopt in the end. I am not sure if the last one is possible or not, which is why I am here. I will list the solutions I have at the moment:

1. Re-scan and reload all fixtures before every test, coupling the fixture creation logic & setup logic together. This is obviously inefficient
2. Require a dependency to be requested with some wrapper, like:

```java
public Fixture<Database> database(Dependency<Connection> connection){
  return Fixtures.provide(()->new Database(connection.get().getURL());
}
```

And then when running tests, set the value of the `Dependency` object when the relevant fixture is setup. This is probably the simplest solution in terms of complexity, but it's clunky.

3. Dynamically create some proxy object as the dependency. When the fixtures are being loaded, that proxy points nowhere. When the fixtures are enabled, the proxy points to that fixture. In the above example, `connection` would be a dynamically created proxy that initially points to nothing, and then when the connection is set up the proxy would point to the loaded connection, calling `getURL()` on the actual connection. Such a setup seems to be possible with ByteBuddy.

While solution #3 seems to provide the cleanest solution (even though it is a little more complex than the others), I have a problem with it - is there a way to delegate property calls, not just methods? For example, let's assume for some reason the `Connection` object above had a publically exposed `url` property instead of a getter; is it possible to create a dynamic proxy that forwards **property** access to another object? From my research I could not find a way, so I am asking here.

(I have considered just forwarding methods, and then having a disclaimer that getters should always be used. It would just be a shame if arrays could not be used as fixtures, since they have a pretty standard property of array.length)

Thank you!

Update: I thought about it more and #1 doesn't seem so bad. Using reflection is somewhat slower but JUnit uses reflection for setup/teardown anyhow. Would make for a cleaner design. Still, any thoughts on the above would be appreciated.